# Why do I get duplicated data from flink?

Tags: java, apache-flink

I'm new to flink, and I'm trying to read a stream from kafka, however I'm  getting duplicate data processed, and I'm wondering why ?

I know that's the problem came from flink because when I wrote a simple consumer in java I got no duplicate data

flink-connector-kafka_2.11 version 1.10.0 
flink version 1.11

is there any issue to check if flink is processing only once the data provided by kafka ?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        KafkaConsumer consumer = new KafkaConsumer("fashion","172.16.3.241:9092","fashion","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteBufferDeserializer");
        FlinkKafkaConsumer<JsonNode> stream_consumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>(consumer.getTopic(), new DeserializationSchema<JsonNode>() {
            private final ObjectMapper objMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            @Override
            public JsonNode deserialize(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
                return objMapper.readValue(bytes,JsonNode.class);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isEndOfStream(JsonNode jsonNode) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public TypeInformation<JsonNode> getProducedType() {
                return TypeExtractor.getForClass(JsonNode.class);
            }
        }, consumer.getProperties());
        DataStream<JsonNode> tweets = env.addSource(stream_consumer);
        tweets.flatMap(new getTweetSchema());
        env.execute("Flink Streaming Java API Skeleton");

    }
```

```
private static class getTweetSchema implements FlatMapFunction<JsonNode, Tweet>{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -6867736771747690202L;
        private JSONObject objTweet;
        public void flatMap(JsonNode tweet, Collector<Tweet> out) throws JSONException, ParseException{
            try{
                if (objTweet == null){
                    objTweet = new JSONObject(tweet.asText());
                }
                HashSet<String> hashtag = new HashSet<>();
                String text = objTweet.get("text").toString();
                DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH );
                Date created_at = dateFormat.parse(objTweet.get("created_at").toString());
                String source = objTweet.get("source").toString();
                source = source.substring(source.length() - 11).replaceAll("</a>","");
                String lang = objTweet.get("lang").toString();
                Boolean isRT = text.matches("^RT.*");
                Long id = Long.parseLong(objTweet.get("id").toString());
                if (objTweet.has("extended_tweet")){
                    JSONArray arr = objTweet.getJSONObject("extended_tweet").getJSONObject("entities").getJSONArray("hashtags");
                    if(!(arr.isEmpty())){
                        for(int i = 0; i< arr.length();i++){
                            hashtag.add(arr.getJSONObject(i).get("text").toString());
                        }
                        System.out.println(arr);
                    }
                }
                out.collect(new Tweet(id, text,created_at,source,lang,isRT,hashtag));
            }catch (JSONException | ParseException e){
                System.out.println("e");
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: (1) It looks like you are using the wrong version of the connector -- you need to use the 1.11.x connector with Flink 1.11.x. (2) I don't see a sink. Every Flink job needs at least one sink. (3) How are you observing that there is duplication?

Comment: yep i forgot to add the .print(), I will try the version of the connector and see if it's work, thank you !!

Comment: it doesn't change, always with the same problem @DavidAnderson